# Why does my program go into an infinite loop?

Tags: c++, arrays, conways-game-of-life

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>


int main(){

    int r,c,g;

    std::cin>>r>>c>>g;

    char box[r][c];
    char copy[r][c];

    for(int i = 0; i < r; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < c; ++j){
            std::cin >> box[i][j];
            }
    }
    
    
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<c;j++){
            copy[i][j] = box[i][j];
        }
    }


    //making a copy of box
    for(int i=0;i<g;i++){
        int count = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<r; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<c; j++){
                count =0;
                
                 if((i-1 >= 0 ) && (j-1>=0)) {
                     if(copy[i-1][j-1] == '*'){
                       count+=1;
                   }
                 }
                   
                   
                if(j-1>=0){
                   if(copy[i][j-1] == '*'){
                       count+=1;
                   }
                }
                
                
                if((i+1 < r ) && (j-1>=0)){
                   if(copy[i+1][j-1] == '*'){
                       count+=1;
                   }
                 }
                 
                 if(i+1<r){
                   if(copy[i+1][j] == '*'){
                       count+=1;
                   }
                 }
                 
                 if((i+1<r) && (j+1<c)){
                   if(copy[i+1][j+1] == '*'){
                       count+=1;
                   }
                 }
                 
                 if(j+1<c){
                   if(copy[i][j+1] == '*'){
                       count+=1;
                   }
                 }
                 
                 
                 if ((i-1>=0) && (j+1<c)){
                   if(copy[i-1][j+1] == '*'){
                       count+=1;
                   }
                 }
                 if (i-1>=0){
                   if(copy[i-1][j] == '*'){
                       count+=1;
                   }

                 }
                 
            //modify the original grid based on the rules
            if ((count<2) || (count>3)){
                box[i][j] = '.';
            }

            if((copy[i][j]=='.') && (count == 3)){
                box[i][j] = '*';
            }
            
            
           
        
            } 
        }

            
         for(int i=0;i<r;i++){
             for(int j=0;j<c;j++){
                 box[i][j] = copy[i][j];
                }   
            }        
        }
    
    
        for(int i=0; i<r; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<c; j++){
                if (j < c - 1){
                    std::cout<<box[i][j]<<" ";
                }
                else{
                    std::cout<<box[i][j];
                }
    
            }
            std::cout<<std::endl;
        }
    
    
    
    
}
```

So for some context, I must implement Conway's Game of Life using a two-dimensional array as a grid in which I store the cells. Live cells are denoted as * characters, dead cells are denoted by the '.' character.
[image]

The rules for the game are as followed:

- Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbors dies (as if by underpopulation).
- Any live cell with more than three live neighbors dies (as if by overpopulation/overcrowding).
- Any live cell with two or three live neighbors lives, unchanged, to the next generation.
- Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbors will come to life (as if by reanimation or birth).
- Neighbors refer to the eight cells adjacent to any given cell in a grid, with the exception of border cells.

Now I must check the copy of the initial grid and count the cells and modify the original based on these rules:
[image]

Ive been debugging for hours and I really don't understand why my code goes into an infinite loop?

Comment: In the second for loop you've got two i's and the j bit increments i instead of j.

Comment: oh shoot i saw this already and I forgot to copy and paste the updated code

Comment: Even if you fix that... `copy[r][c] = box[r][c]` - You *really* want *that*, as in *that statement*,  as the operative code in a nested for-i-for-j loop set ? A statement that invokes *undefined behavior* over and over again on the same bogus element ? I think you need to sit down with [a dubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) and verbally explain what each step in your code does. Not just what you think it does; what it actually *says* it does.

Comment: ok i fixed that now it just prints out the same exact board twice !?!?

Comment: i see what u mean about the same bogus element it should be I j in the operative code

Comment: The outer `for(int i=1;i<=g;i++)` is that little trio is also completely pointless. And this: `if(i != 0 || i != c-1 || j != 0 || j != r-1)` needs *serious* rubber duck debugging . I suspect your usage of `||` is not proper for what you think that expression does. So long as `c` and `r` are both not `1` that expression as-is will *always* be true, and I'm confident that isn't by intent.

Comment: if i were to say (i<0 || i>=row and j<0 || j>=col this statement would mean it was on the border and it would not count the adjacent neighbors

Comment: You completely missed the point. Choose any numbers `r` and `c` that are *not* `1`. Now, look at that expression and think of *any* values `i` and `j` where complete expression is *false* ? There are none, because what you *really* meant in all of those terms was `&&`, not `||`. You said "Ive been debugging for hours and I really don't understand why my code goes into an infinite loop?" - What exactly have you been *doing* for those hours? I'm not even using a *debugger* and I can see the problems I'm listing off. Surely you've seen them using a *debugger*. You *are* using a *debugger*, right?

Comment: BTW the statement `char box[r][c];` is not standard C++, as variable length arrays are not standard.  Use `std::vector` or dynamically allocate the memory.  You may be using a compiler that supports VLAs as an extension, but not all compilers support it.

Comment: im not using a debugger im just using my brain and its not working properly ;(

Comment: ***im just using my brain and its not working properly*** When debugging in your head no longer is effective the next step is to debugger like the one in Visual Studio or gdb.

Answer (score 1):

Usually infinite loops come from blunders, I read really quickly your code and spotted that inside the nested loop where you copy the box specifically at the most inner loop you increase **i** instead of **j**:

Comment: i fixed that part